# Cropped Image is not aligned in center

Tags: windows-phone-7, crop

I am developing a Photo App in Windows phone 7.

When I crop the image by a Rectangle area, the Cropped image aligned to the top-left corner of the image control. I want to align the image in center and zoom/stretch it to the full image control.

See the figures.

[image: Before Crop]

[image: After Crop]

1st Image shows Before Crop and 2nd Image shows after crop, the image aligned top-left corner. the cropped image should be aligned in center. And plz also see the cropped image is not fully come in figure-2, I mean the Portion of Boot of Player is also cropped, but not showing in the cropped image, why this?

Code is:

```
    void ClipImage()
    {
        RectangleGeometry geo = new RectangleGeometry();

        r = (Rectangle)(from c in ImageLayout.Children where c.Opacity == .5 select    
      c).First();
        GeneralTransform gt = r.TransformToVisual(ImageLayout);
        Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        geo.Rect = new Rect(p.X, p.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
        ImageMain.Clip = geo;
        r.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform();
        t.X = -p.X;
        t.Y = -p.Y;
        ImageMain.RenderTransform = t;
    }
```

Here in code, I think some values should be changed, to align the image in center. This is just a cropped image code, many other functions also used inside, but is not concerned I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center some XAML element, use `HorizontaAlignment.Center` and `VerticalAlignment.Center`.

Comment: No, this is not aligning via Xaml, this is done by hard code, so hows?